# What's the relationship between a polynomial $P_{n}\left(x\right)$ and $P_{n}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying for my final exam in differential equations and I'm rethinking the whole concept of a characteristic equation. For instance, if we have the DE
\begin{align}0&=\sum_{\kappa=0}^{2}\frac{d^{\kappa}}{{dx}^{\kappa}}y\left(x\right)\\&=L\left[y\left(x\right)\right],\end{align}
by supposing $y\left(x\right)=e^{rx}$, we would arrive at the characteristic polynomial
\begin{align}r^{2}+r+1&=0.\end{align}
Now, if I just substitute $r\mapsto\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}$ I get the operator $L$ back.

Can I substitute $x\mapsto\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}$ in $\mathbb{P}_{n}\left[x\right]$ to write $\mathbb{P}_{n}[\,\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\,]$? Is this the same as the operator $L$? Or does this notation not make sense? I'm basically thinking of a set that looks like
\begin{align}\mathbb{P}_{n}[\,\frac{d}{dx}\,]=\left\{I,\frac{d}{dx},\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{2},\cdots,\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n}\right\},\end{align}
where $Iy\left(x\right)=y\left(x\right)$, instead of
\begin{align}\mathbb{P}_{n}[\,x\,]=\left\{1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^{n}\right\}.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just notation? $x$ is an expression and $\frac{d}{dx}$ is an operator; they're two different things. We write $\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n$ similarly to $x^n$ as a matter of convention, probably because applying an operator an integer number of times is conceptually similar to integer exponentiation.

But you can't just take any expression and replace $x$ with $\frac{d}{dx}$ and expect it to mean anything. For example, $x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0$ makes sense and has a meaningful solution whereas $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} - 2 \frac{d}{dx} + 1 = 0$ is gibberish. The analogy only works when you consider something such as $\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2} - 2 \frac{d}{dx} + 1\right)[x] = 0$. That is, an operator needs an operand to form an expression, whereas a variable such as $x$ is itself an expression.

Comment: I see, thanks for your suggestions/comments!